# Kafka ACL's cause topic replication to fail

Tags: apache-kafka

Good morning,

A bit of background for you: We are currently putting together a POC to use Apache Kafka as a messaging queue for inbound log data for post processing by Elastic Logstash. Currently I have 3 broker nodes configured to point to a single zookeeper node. I have a default replication factor of 3 and minumum ISR of 2 to account for a single node failure(or availability zone in this case). When creating a topic I set a partition count of 10 and replication factor of 3 - Kafka duly goes and creates the topic - happy days! However, because I use SSL on my inbound interface(because it will be internet facing) I need to secure the topics to be writable by a a certain principal as follows:

```
/opt/kafka-dq/bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zookeeper-001:2181 --add --allow-principal User:USER01 --producer --topic 'USER01_openvpn'
```

When this happens the ISR drops to a single node, and as I have a minimum ISR of 2 the partitions are taken offline which causes filebeat(client end) to start throwing the following errors:

```
kafka/client.go:242     Kafka publish failed with: circuit breaker is open
```

The following errors are also seen in the kafka server logs

```
2018-11-16 09:59:12,736] ERROR [Controller id=3] Received error in LeaderAndIsr response LeaderAndIsrResponse(responses={USER01_openvpn-3=CLUSTER_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED, USER01_openvpn-2=CLUSTER_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED...

[2018-11-16 10:09:46,852] ERROR [Controller id=2 epoch=23] Controller 2 
epoch 23 failed to change state for partition USER01_openvpn-4 from 
OnlinePartition to OnlinePartition (state.change.logger)
kafka.common.StateChangeFailedException: Failed to elect leader for 
partition USER01_openvpn-4 under strategy 
PreferredReplicaPartitionLeaderElectionStrategy
```

I have attempted to remedy this by adding an ACL for the ANONYMOUS user to all topics but this actually caused the cluster to break further. For further clarity, whilst I have SSL enabled on the inbound interface my cluster inter-broker comms is plaintext.

The documentation around ACL's for the cluster itself are somewhat "wooly" at best so wondered how best to approach this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing an ACL with `ClusterAction` on the `Cluster` resource for your brokers. This is required to allow them to exchange inter-broker messages.

As your brokers are using plaintext, you probably need to set this ACL on the `ANONYMOUS` principal.

If you're using only SSL (without SASL), you want to make sure you do [SSL authentication](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_ssl), otherwise anybody could connect to your cluster and would get `ClusterAction` permissions allowing them to cause havoc.